# Extending a label control to allow bold segments in the text

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, inheritance, label

I am trying to extend the label control (winforms) to display bold segments based on html "b" tags.

As you can see in the OnPain method below, the location the text is drawn is based on a point (x,y). This works fine until the text goes beyond the horizontal bounds of the control.

Example - if I set this as label text:

`<b>Line 1 is Bold</b>
Line 2 is Regular
Line 3 is both <b>Bold</b> and Regular (drawn 3 times)
Line 4 is a biiiiiig line with <b>Bold</b> and regular words that will easily exceed the control bounds and if I use rectangles to determine the bounds I will end up with something like this. 
Line 5 is a Regular again.`

Using DrawText based on point(x,y) - as is currently:
[image]

If I change the code to draw in rectangles instead, I get something like this because one line can potentially be drawn several times:
[image]

Can you please give me ideas on how to solve this?
Here is my OnPaint method:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)

    'splitter will contain our <b></b> tags
    Dim parts = Me.Text.Split(Splitters, StringSplitOptions.None)

    If parts.Length > 1 Then
        'we have <b></b> tags- first we need to determine if text should start as bold  
        Dim drawBold As Boolean = False
        If Me.Text.Length > 3 Then
            If Me.Text.Substring(0, 3).ToLower = "<b>" Then
                drawBold = True
            End If
        End If

        Dim textBrush As SolidBrush = Nothing, backBrush As SolidBrush
        Dim textFont As Font = Nothing
        backBrush = New SolidBrush(BackColor)

        'create the box to draw in
        Dim x As Single = Me.Padding.Left
        Dim y As Single = 0F
        Dim h As Single = 0F
        Dim w As Single = 0F
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backBrush, Me.ClientRectangle)

        textBrush = New SolidBrush(ForeColor)
        For Each part As String In parts
            Dim box As SizeF = Size.Empty

            'if this bold/notbold piece of text contains linebreaks we will need to split further
            Dim lines = part.Split(LineBreakers, StringSplitOptions.None)
            For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1

                If i > 0 Then
                    'this as new line, need to reset x
                    box = Size.Empty
                    x = Me.Padding.Left
                    y += h
                End If

                If drawBold Then
                    textFont = New Font(Me.Font.FontFamily, Me.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point)
                    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, lines(i), textFont, New Point(CInt(x), CInt(y)), ForeColor, BackColor, TextFormatFlags.WordBreak)
                    box = e.Graphics.MeasureString(lines(i), textFont)
                Else
                    textFont = New Font(Me.Font.FontFamily, Me.Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point)
                    TextRenderer.DrawText((e.Graphics, lines(i), textFont, New Point(CInt(x), CInt(y)), ForeColor, BackColor, TextFormatFlags.WordBreak)
                    box = e.Graphics.MeasureString(lines(i), textFont)
                End If

                'keep count of x-position
                x += box.Width
                'check if a dimension has grown
                w = Math.Max(w, x)
                h = Math.Max(h, box.Height)
            Next
            drawBold = Not drawBold
            'add extra margin to separate bold and regular text
            x += CSng(4)
        Next

        'final adjustments - control size
        Me.Width = CInt(w)
        Me.Height = CInt(y + h)
        ' clean up
        textBrush.Dispose()
        backBrush.Dispose()
        If textFont IsNot Nothing Then
            textFont.Dispose()
        End If
    Else
        'this text has no tags, let the base event kick in instead
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: [Rich Text Label](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6491/RichTextLabel-WinForms-Control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted!
The solution may not be very elegant... but works. Basically, validate if the line exceeds the boundaries of the control, and if it does, measure the string character by character until size is just right. Then remove the original string from the list and replace it by the split version (2 strings).

The split is done by this function:

```
Private Function breakLongString(g As Drawing.Graphics, ByVal textToBreak As String, ByVal textFont As Font, ByVal sizeLimit As Single, ByVal startingXPosition As Single) As String()

    Dim WidthSoFar As Single
    Dim iChar As Integer = 0
    While iChar < textToBreak.Length - 1
        WidthSoFar = g.MeasureString(textToBreak.Substring(0, iChar), textFont).Width + startingXPosition
        If WidthSoFar >= sizeLimit Then
            Exit While
        Else
            iChar = iChar + 1
        End If
    End While
    'now reverse until we find a " " (blank space) so we dont break a word
    While iChar > 0
        If textToBreak.Substring(iChar, 1) = " " Then
            Exit While
        Else
            iChar = iChar - 1
        End If
    End While

    Dim text1 = Trim(textToBreak.Substring(0, iChar))
    Dim text2 = Trim(textToBreak.Substring(iChar, textToBreak.Length - iChar - 1))

    Return {text1, text2}

End Function
```

I just need to call this function right before the DrawText method:

```
textFont = New Font(Me.Font.FontFamily, Me.Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point)

Dim LineWidth = e.Graphics.MeasureString(lines(iLine), textFont).Width + x
Dim BoundsWidth = Me.Parent.Width

If LineWidth > BoundsWidth Then
    'we have a problem as the line width is bigger than the control, need to split even further
    Dim textToBreak As String = lines(iLine)
    'remove this text from the list to add it split (as 2 lines)
    lines.RemoveAt(iLine)
    lines.InsertRange(iLine, breakLongString(e.Graphics, textToBreak, textFont, BoundsWidth, x))
End If

TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, lines(iLine), textFont, New Point(CInt(x), CInt(y)), ForeColor, BackColor, TextFormatFlags.WordBreak)
```

Again, the solution is not elegant, but works.
You're welcome to leave any feedback.